# Error: grid.mongo.GridStore is not a consstructor ,Using mongoose, Grid-fs-stream and grid multer storage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs, multer-gridfs-storage

I am getting the following error mentioned.
The basic configs are as follow:
I have uploaded the files on the server
I want to download them but getting these errors
I called a POST request to /api/files/delete/${fileId}
Which should call the route and give back the file to the browser instead getting the error with the Grid related module.

```
MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING = mongodb://localhost:27017/Cstore

Db structure={Cstore:{uploads.files,uploads.chunks,users}}

On requesting POST         axios.post(`/api/files/delete/${fileId}`)

Getting error: 

     this._store = new grid.mongo.GridStore(grid.db, this.id || new grid.mongo.ObjectID(), this.name, this.mode, options);
[0]                 ^
[0] 
[0] TypeError: grid.mongo.GridStore is not a constructor
[0]     at new GridReadStream (/home/lenovo/Desktop/react/cstore/node_modules/gridfs-stream/lib/readstream.js:68:17)

This is server.js

      app.get('/image/:filename', (req, res) => {
    gfs.files.findOne({ 
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.filename)
      // filename: req.params.filename.toString()
    }, (err, file) => {
      // Check if file
      if (!file || file.length === 0) {
        console.log("not found")
        return res.status(404).json({
          
          err: 'No file exists'
        });
      }

      // Check if image
      if (file.contentType === 'image/jpeg' || file.contentType === 'image/png') {
        // Read output to browser
        console.log(file)
        let id=file._id;

        const readStream = gfs.createReadStream(
          {
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.filename)
          }
          // {
          // _id: id
          // }
        )
        readStream.on('error', err => {
            // report stream error
            console.log(err);
        });
        // the response will be the file itself.
        readStream.pipe(res);

      //   let readstream = gfs.createReadStream(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(file._id))
      //   readstream.pipe(res)
      // } else {
        res.status(404).json({
          err: 'Not an image'
        });
      }
    });
  });



  

    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
      mongoose.connect(
        mongoURI,
        {
          useNewUrlParser: true,
          useUnifiedTopology: true,
        },
        (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('MongoDB connection established');
        }
      )
      const connection = mongoose.connection;
    
      ///  HANDLING FILE
      let gfs;
      connection.once('open', () => {
        // Init stream
        gfs = Grid(connection.db, mongoose.mongo);
        gfs.collection('uploads');
      });
    
      const storage = new GridFsStorage({
        url: mongoURI, 
        file: (req, file) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
              if (err) {
                return reject(err);
              }
              const filename = file.originalname;
              const fileInfo = {
                filename: filename,
                bucketName: 'uploads'
              };
              resolve(fileInfo);
            });
          });
        }
      })
    
      const upload = multer({ storage });

Initial:
  const express = require('express');
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
  const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
  const path = require('path');

  const multer = require('multer');
  const {GridFsStorage} = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
  const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
  const methodOverride = require('method-override')
  const crypto = require('crypto')

  const app = express();

  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
  app.use(cookieParser());

  const dotenv=require('dotenv');
  dotenv.config({path:__dirname+'/.env'});

  const mongoURI = process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also faced similar issues. The resolution for me was with mongoose version. The issue arises in the version 6.0.5 but is working in the version 5.13.7

Comment: changing the version helped

Comment: I changed version, it helped but now it is giving deprecation warnings. This is not a stable solution

Answer (score 6):

GridStore is deprecated. You can use the GridFSBucket instance to call read and write operations on the files in your bucket. [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/gridfs/#std-label-gridfs-create-bucket)

```
 let gfs, gridfsBucket;
  conn.once('open', () => {
   gridfsBucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db, {
   bucketName: 'your_bucket_name'
 });

   gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
   gfs.collection('your_bucket_name');
})
```

and

```
if(file.contentType === 'image/jpeg' || file.contentType 
 ==='image/png') 
 {
    const readStream = gridfsBucket.openDownloadStream(file._id);
    readStream.pipe(res);
 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

GridStore is deprecated in mongoose version 6+.

One solution is to deprecate mongoose version to use 5+

other solution is to use GridFsBucket

```
import grid from 'gridfs-stream';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

let gfs, gridfsBucket; // declare one more variable with name gridfsBucket
const conn = mongoose.connection;
conn.once('open', () => {
    // Add this line in the code
    gridfsBucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db, {
        bucketName: 'bucket_name'
    });
    gfs = grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.collection('bucket_name');
});

export const getImage = async (request, response) => {
    try {   
        const file = await gfs.files.findOne({ filename: request.params.filename });
        // Till version 5+ we were using this 
        // const readStream = gfs.createReadStream(file.filename);
        // readStream.pipe(response);
        // For version 6+, Replace these two lines with the lines below
        const readStream = gridfsBucket.openDownloadStream(file._id);
        readStream.pipe(response);
    } catch (error) {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GridFs bucket`. Here is a good tutorial that I found on the internet, it demonstrates how to upload and download image from the mongodb bucket. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/gridfs-making-file-uploading-to-mongodb/

Comment: The link no longer works!

Comment: @WolfG I've updated the link to another useful resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GridFsBucket instead.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Grid = require("gridfs-stream")

let gfs, gridfsBucket

const conn = mongoose.connection

conn.once('open', () => {
    // initialise stream
    gridfsBucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db, {
        bucketName: "photos"
    })
    gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo)
    gfs.collection('photos')
})

const render_file = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // find file from database
        const file = gfs.files.findOne({ filename: filename})
        // check if file exists or not
        if (!await file) {
            return res.status(500).send({
                message: "No file found!",
            })
        }

        // check if the file is an image
        if (await file.contentType == 'image/jpeg' || await file.contentType == 'image/png') {
            // render the image to the browser
            var readStream = gridfsBucket.openDownloadStreamByName(filename)
            readStream.pipe(res)
        } else {
            res.status(404).json({
                err: 'File is not an image'
            })
        }

    } catch (err) {     
        return res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message,
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue on mongoose-gridfs 1.3.0

It seems like now you need to use the bucket to create a stream instead of the gridfs constructor.

This solution is for commonjs libs

```
    const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
    const systemBucket = 'YourBucketName'
    const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');

exports.renderImage = async (req, res) => {

      gfs = Grid(connection.db, mongoose.mongo);
        const ResourceBucket = createModel({ systemBucket }); 
        try {
           const id = new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(req.params.id);
           const file = await ResourceBucket.findOne(id);
            if (!file || file.length === 0) {
                return res.status(404).json({err: 'No File Exists'});
            } else {
                const _id = file._id;            
                const readStream = ResourceBucket.read({ _id });
                readStream.pipe(res);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(500).send(error)
        }
}
```