# TypeError: grid.mongo.GridStore is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs, gridfs-stream

I'm trying to use gridfs-stream to retrieve images I uploaded using multer. The following code is responding with `TypeError: grid.mongo.GridStore is not a constructor at new GridReadStream` Someone in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69055292/error-grid-mongo-gridstore-is-not-a-consstructor-using-mongoose-grid-fs-strea) thread suggests that using a different mongoose version would solve the problem but I'm looking for a more sustainable solution.

```
const Grid = require("gridfs-stream");

let gfs;
//mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    gfs = Grid(connection.db, mongoose.mongo);
})

app.get("/files", async (req, res) => {
    try {
       //const file = await gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename });
        const readStream = gfs.createReadStream({filename:'09ff76ee0d54433c1090117e479f679e.jpg'});
        readStream.pipe(res); 
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.send(error);
    }
});
```

mongoose 6.0.11 ,
gridfs-stream 1.1.1

Answer (score 3):

i had this problem.
The reason is that .GridStore is deprecated after the mongoose 6.0.5 version.

For solved i to this.

Create a second variable with the name

```
conection.once('open', () => {
  //Init Stream
  gridfsBucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conection.db, {
    bucketName: 'uploads'
  })
  gfs = Grid(conection.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('uploads');
})
```

And for get the file I use that variable of this form.

```
const readStream = gridfsBucket.openDownloadStream(file._id);
readStream.pipe(res)
```