# TypeError: grid.mongo.GridStore is not a constructor when I try to read stream with Grid

Tags: node.js, mongoose, node-modules, gridfs-stream, multer-gridfs-storage

I'm using GridFsStorage with multer.
This is my code that outputs a TypeError.

```
const mongoURI=DB


const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);

let gfs;
conn.once('open', function() {
  //STREAM INITIALIZING
  gfs=GridFSBucket(conn.db, mongoose.mongo)
  gfs.collection('uploads')
})



 gfs.files.findOne({filename:req.params.filename},(err,file)=>{
    const readstream = gfs.createReadStream(file.filename)
    readstream.pipe(res)
  })
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: grid.mongo.GridStore is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69962704/typeerror-grid-mongo-gridstore-is-not-a-constructor)

Answer (score -1):

I also had this problem. The reason is that .GridStore is deprecated after mongoose 6.0.5.

To solve this, create a second variable with the name:

```
conection.once('open', () => {
  //Init Stream
  gridfsBucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conection.db, {
    bucketName: 'uploads'
  })
  gfs = Grid(conection.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('uploads');
})
```

And to get the file, I used a variable of this form:

```
const readStream = gridfsBucket.openDownloadStream(file._id);
readStream.pipe(res)
```

Comment: Posting the same answer twice on different questions is something that should be avoided. In this particular case, it was not possible to vote one to be close as a dup over another. But you still shouldn't do that.